# Class declaration in a header file and static variables

Tags: c++, class, initialization, header-files, static-members

Noob question, but would like to understand the following:

Imagine I have a **multifile project**. I'm specifying a **class** in a **header file** to be shared among all the files in the project, and I write this : `static int test = 0;` and in the next line this: `static const int MAX = 4;`

The first one would be an error trying to compile because of the one definition rule. But the second one will compile without errors. Why?

From what I understand, both have the same properties: whole execution storage duration, class scope and no linkage.

Any help?

EDIT: testing an external constant declaration in a header: `extern const int MAX = 4;` to force external linkage produced the expected error. So I don't understand why with the variable it gives me the error and with the constant it doesn't.

Comment: Did you mean `static const int MAX = 4;`?

Comment: @Tom Kerr oops, sorry. corrected.

Comment: @Tom isn't there a default int rule in C++?

Comment: @Qnan I assumed he meant int, but I didn't want to edit and change the meaning of his question.  If he (or others reading the question later) didn't know, then the question asks different things.  I *believe* that they are equivalent however.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
static const int test = 0;
```

I've sometimes noticed compiler errors with the immediate initialization of static const variables in the header file. You can always use the declaration in the header

```
class MyClass
{
    // ...
    static const int test;
    // ...
}
```

and initialize it in the corresponding .cpp file

```
const int MyClass::test = 0;
```

This should work properly with any other types than `int` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Integer constants in C++ don't actually occupy any space in the object and don't act like variables in general. Think about them more like numbers that are given names in this particular context.

Comment: @Qnan But I'm declaring the same thing in all the files. It should be an error. Constants declared externally without static have internal linkage to let you add them in header files. But in this case I'm using static.

Comment: @Kurospidey nope, it goes to a special place in the memory and whenever you use it in the code the compiler will most likely substitute the actual value for the name. I.e. there's no declaration/definition thing with the constants, it's just giving a number a new name.

Comment: @Kurospidey, `static` _forces_ internal linkage, you mixed all up .

Comment: @Qnan so wouldn't the compiler protest for giving a number a new name twice? So i can put two lines like this one after the other: const int MAX = 4; const int MAX = 4;

Comment: @Kurospidey, this depends on the compiler. I expect you will get at least a warning and most likely an error, since that doesn't make sense. However, #include<> isn't quite as dumb as you seem to think :) It doesn't just stuff the code into every source file, or so I believe.

Comment: @Qnan, thanks for your help. i tried what I said and the compiler didn't give me any errors. OTOH, I tested declaring a constant in a header file as extern const MAX = 4; to override the default internal linkage and the compiler gave me an error. I don't understand the differences between the variable and the const. If I can't initialize the variable in the header because of the one definition rule, I shouldn't be able to initialize the constant either. And if what you said was true always, forcing the const to have external linkage with extern should produce no errors...